# Centre of mass of a hollow cone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Here why have we taken the element of width $dh \, \sec x$? Won't the width be uniform everywhere? Why can't we take it as $dh$? Aren't $dh$ and $dh \, \sec x$ equal as they're the width of the same cross section?

Comment: This question isn't really about physics as posed — it's about geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you're interested in the outside surface of the cone.  You're adding up little cylindrical strips, each of which has a height $\frac{dh}{\cos x}$.  It has been done this way because by integrating in $h$, it's easier incorporate the radius of the cylindrical strips, $r = h \tan x$.